# Given sorted array except 2 swapped elements . sort it in linear time

Tags: python, sorting

Problem statement:

```
 Given an integer array where all its elements are sorted in 
 increasing order except two swapped elements, sort it in linear time.
 Assume there are no duplicates in the array.

 input: [3,8,6,7,5,9] or [3,5,6,9,8,7] [3,5,7,6,8,9]
 output:[3,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Question: some people's are using different logic and more than 10  line of code(python).
but I am using  sort() build in function in python to solving this problem single
line,
my question is my logic is correct or not .

Comment: It's `sorted()`, not `sort()`. At any rate, since this is almost certainly an assignment, I would imagine they want you to execute the sort *without* using the built-in...

Comment: The output will be correct, but you will not have solved the problem.  The problem statement says you must sort the array in linear time.  That means you can't use any general sort algorithm, since the best they can do is O(n*log(n)) rather than the required O(n).  You need to write a specialized sort that handles this simplified problem where you know only two elements are out-of-order.

Comment: @MattDMo More to the point, using a builtin sort function won't solve this problem, since it must run in linear time.